# Ubuntu restarts nightly at 12:00 EST. Why?

Tags: restart

Title says it all really.

But every night, unless I'm actively using it, my computer restarts, and every time, at midnight.  I was wondering if their is anything I can do to stop it, or to find out what's actually causing it, or any help in general.

I'm using 12.04 LTS.

Comment: you can check `dmesg` command, `/var/log/message` file and if `crontab` has anything fishy.

Comment: What would I look for with dmesg?  No /var/log/message file.  And what would I look for in crontab?  Their are a couple things in the files.

Comment: As to the crontab you can check if any of the rules are firing off at the time in question. As to `dmesg`, you could run `watch 'sudo dmesg -c >> /tmp/dmesg.log'` just before it is supposed to restart and check what are the last few messages after it does. and is it `/var/log/messages`

Comment: What do you mean by "restarts?" Is the machine powered off, and then boots on it's own accord at midnight? If it is doing that then perhaps the RTC is generating a wakealarm event and this triggers the machine to wakeup.

Comment: What is the output of: `sudo crontab -l` and `crontab -l`? This will help to know if any cron jobs have been scheduled.

Comment: I did that earlier, and again, no crontab for root, nor for user.  I'll try out the dmesg too closer to the time.

Comment: Machine is powered on, it just restarts if I'm not on it.

Comment: I should add in, I don't know if I was seeing things because I was expecting it to happen, but I watched it two nights ago, and like, a minute to three it flickered, but I was on it (Stopped moving the mouse when it flickered) and it didn't restart.